# Salesforce Mobile and Visualforce Page on Android

Tags: visualforce, mobile

I'm facing a problem with a Salesforce Mobile application (I use the Salesforce Classic app with mobile licence).

In the application I have created a custom formula field on the `Contact` in order to access to a Visualforce Page (visualforce:///apex/MyPage?Id=XXXX). When the user clicks on the link, the page is opened  inside the app. After filling some fields, the page call a second Visualforce Page thanks to a `commandButton`.

The problem is this :
 When the user is on the second page, he can't go back directly to the app, on the Contact where he came from. He needs to press the back button of his mobile several time (and the first page seems to "block" the back action, you need to quicky press the back button ).

So, here's my question :
 Is there a way to directly go back to the Salesforce app thanks to a `commandButton` ? Or is it possible to open the Visualforce page in the android native browser ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have your tried using a button backed by javascript that closes the window via window.close()?

Comment: Yes and that doesn't work. Finally we have decided to open the browser instead of staying in the app

Comment: Might be you could also use a Publisher action to go to the VF page and when you finish you can redirect. Custom Publisher actions are in Salesforce 1 app.

Comment: Can you clarify, are you trying to navigate backwards within the app, or are you trying to use a URL outside of the app (i.e. in the Android browser) to open the app?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though your second page that the command button takes you to needs to have a mobile card added to the VisualForce page for it which includes a link to return to Contacts, Home, etc in your app.